# Android web application server error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing an application to use GCM method, I also developed the server-side which use Tomcat 7.0.
I wish to use web server to push the message to multiple users.But in the dynamic web project I cannot

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender
```

It is under red line,can someone  help me to solve this problem? I have already put Google Play lib as the reference library in Client side.For the server-side problem I have no idea to solve it.

Comment: remove your library and add again then clean and build your workspace

Comment: @micky I tried before also but problem still the same.. The problem happened in Dynamic Web project, it is my server-side.